# changing the function color in theme rstudio 1.2

Tags: rstudio

I downloaded the latest version of Rstudio to be able to customize theme.

I followed this tuto to install the panda theme : 
https://towardsdatascience.com/customize-your-rstudio-theme-914cca8b04b1

The theme should look like this :

[image]

It worked but there is an issues : the functions didn't get the pink color :

[image]

Everything else is ok, but I have no way to get colored function. Can you help me find out the reason ?

Sorry I couldn't post image in the post because I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Are the available themes under Tools->Global Options->Appearance not good enough for you?!

Comment: Looks neat but not sure this question belongs on StackOverflow.

Comment: @NelsonGon They are so poor compared to what others programmation language has. A good theme offer so much lisibility

Comment: Alright, then. I personally think they're great! In fact, better than the others I use.

Comment: If you need help specifically with RStudio, it's probably better to ask for help at https://community.rstudio.com/ rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Tools > Global Options > Code > Display and check the "Highlight R function calls" box.[image]

I was looking for the same answer too! And I hate myself for not knowing there's such option after all these years!

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to change the actual color, modify this value in `c:\program files\Rstudio\resources\app\resources\theme\themename.rstheme` of the current theme, or create your own theme file. (Windows)

```
/* function highlight color */

.ace_entity.ace_name.ace_function,
.ace_support.ace_function,
.ace_variable { color: #7AA6DA }

/* class highlight color */

.ace_support.ace_class,
.ace_support.ace_type {  color: #E7C547 }
```

Although these values have changed in the newest release of RStudio, but should still function.